# How to import posts from instagram in an angular application?

Tags: angular, instagram

I am working on an angular 6 application. There is a section where I display the list of products I have. I used to add the images statically, but now I want the images to be updated in synchronous with my instagram account.

I am searching for a service that allows to get the images imported from my instagram account. I have tried [node-instagram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-instagram), but I didn't know how to get the images. It returned all the profile's data but not the images.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you take a look at instagram's api documentation? https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: I call it from my application using httpClient?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will return image urls for some endpoints.

Comment: this url not working [link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)